# Exception: Bad state: cannot get a field on a DocumentSnapshotPlatform which does not exist provider

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I've a provider stream setup on MyApp.

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final AuthService _auth = AuthService();
    String? _userId = _auth.user?.uid;
    return StreamProvider<UserProfileModel?>(
        initialData: null,
        create: (_) => DatabaseService().userProfileData(_userId),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          final userT = context.watch<UserProfileModel?>();
          final userType = userT?.userType;
          print('User type is: $userType');
          return MaterialApp(
            color: Colors.blueAccent,
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            //home: TOCScreen(),
            home: _auth.user == null
                ? StartScreenMsg()
                : userType == 'Creditor'
                    ? CreditorHomePage()
                    : userType == 'Financial Recovery\nWorker'
                        ? FinancialHomePage()
                        : userType == 'Debtor'
                            ? DebtorHomePage()
                            : HomeScreen(),
```

This gets userType from database and shows the screen accordingly, it works fine but whenever i run the app it gives this exception.

```
════════ Exception caught by provider ══════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown:
An exception was throw by _MapStream<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>, UserProfileModel> listened by

StreamProvider<UserProfileModel?>, but no `catchError` was provided.

Exception:
Bad state: cannot get a field on a DocumentSnapshotPlatform which does not exist

════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

I figured it's because the userId at start is null and due to this, it gives this exception. It causes no crash or bugs, but i don't want the Exception to be showing in Debug console.
Here is the userProfileData code

```dart
Stream<UserProfileModel> userProfileData(String? user) {
    return _firestore
        .collection('users')
        .doc(user)
        .collection('userProfile')
        .doc(user)
        .snapshots()
        .map(_userProfileDataFromSnapshot);
  }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown in the error you provided above, it means that StreamProvider has property called `catchError` which is required to handle errors emitted and also provide fallback in case of errors.

To catch `null`, you could check the approach like in example below.

```
StreamProvider(
  ...
  catchError: (_, __) => null,
  ...
)
```

You could also refer this [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/async/DelegatingFuture/catchError.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, this removed the exception. But i'm not sure if that's all i have to add?

Comment: Hi @user16017178, If the problem is only removal of the exception then there's no need to add to the given answer. You can always browse the documentation provided in the answer and use appropriate properties that can be helpful/useful to you.